# Regex expression to disallow special character in C#

Tags: c#, regex

I know this is not the right question to ask, but I have tried many regex and none of them is working. I want to exclude special character but need to include only **{,},-,:**

I need to exclude **?~@#$%`^<>**

The request is as below:

```
{  
"StoreNumber":"9907<>",
"AssociateId":"tkmadoy",
"PrchgType":"PCY",
"Header":{  
   "ApiVersion":"18.1.0.0",
  "JsonWebToken":null
}
}
```

On json parsing I get the below request:

```
[{"AssociateId":"tkmadoy","StoreNumber":"9907","Header":{"ApiVersion":"18.1.0.0","JsonWebToken":null,"AppVersion":null},"AllowedSLAMilliSeconds":0,"SLARequestKey":null,"PrchgType":1,"PriceChangeEventType":0}]
```

but still the regex doesnt work that can omit special character except some.
I created the below for not allowing html tag and special tag for this.

```
[^!*()\|\'?~@#$%`^<>]+$
```

But none of them is working. I would really appreciate if someone can help me with this.

Comment: What exactly do you want to match? It might be better to use for example a Json parser.

Comment: I changed to json but still it is not giving the desired result.

Comment: It's usually better to specify what you allow than what you disallow. For example, you say, "I need to exclude ?~@#$%`^<>"...well, what about null characters, or British pound signs, or copyright symbols? Do you disallow those as well?

Comment: It would help if you explained [why you need to exclude those characters](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/); they are all valid in JSON strings.

Comment: You use a negated character class to match not those characters 1+ times and then assert the end of the line. You could use a character class to match what you don't want then then replace that with an empty string `[!*()|'?~@#$%`^<>]+` [demo](https://regex101.com/r/t3esSs/1) and omit `$` so you would match them in the whole string.

Comment: @Yash will the answer I gave work in your environment?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to escape most if not all those characters.

```
 [^\?~@#\$%`\^<>]+
```